# how node process run in sequence

Tags: node.js, shell, gulp

Node process is  asynchronous, but how these code run in sequence ?

shell code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

cd app_en_us && gulp transformMarkdown &&
echo 'Transform EN success!'
```

gulp code:

```
gulp.task('transformMarkdown', function(){
var process = require('child_process');

process.exec('cd $SLATE && bundle exec middleman build && echo "transform markdown success!"\
', consoleMsg);
```

});

Every time I run the shell, it will output "transform markdown success!" , and then out put "Transform EN success!";
Why not "Transform EN success!" then "transform markdown success!" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Node process itself is not asynchronous. (Many, many, many things *in* Node are asynchronous, though.)

The Node process does not return control to the bash shell until `process.exec()` runs it's callback. So your callback executes before your next bash command. It is not a daemon and does not force itself to run in the background.

Comment: But if do this:
process.exec('taskA');
process.exec('taskB');

TaskA's result need share to taskB, taskB cannot get result,
the two process is asynchronous ?